# Haskell Ambiguous type variable?

Tags: haskell, fold

if i try to run this msall little code:

```
module Problem14 where 

duplicate = foldl (\acc x -> acc ++ [x,x]) []
```

I get the following error message by GHCi:

```
*Ambiguous type variable `t0' arising from a use of `foldl'
prevents the constraint `(Foldable t0)' from being solved.
Relevant bindings include*
```

Why is GHCi giving me that message?

Comment: Why don't you provide the "Relevant bindings"?

Comment: You need to provide a type signature for `duplicate`, something like `[a] -> [a]` or `Foldable t => t a -> [a]` will work.  GHC doesn't want to default anything for you so it tells you that the type signature is ambiguous.

Comment: Did you try searching SO for this error message? If so what is confusing you about the answers to those other questions?

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know exactly what is meant with relevant bindings, now i know.